# Downcasting from a nested task (Task<Task>) to a outer task or awaiting a nested task is occurred. UnWrap() is suggested

Tags: c#, .net, task

`Running` is giving the following warning from AsyncFixer Visual Studio Extension. How do I use UnWrap with it?

> AsyncFixer05: Downcasting from a nested task (Task) to a outer task or awaiting a nested task is occurred. UnWrap() is suggested.

```cs
public class Client
{
    internal Task Running { get; private set; } = Task.CompletedTask;

    public async Task StartAsync()
    {
        DoDisposeChecks();

        await _semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        try
        {
            if (_cts == null)
            {
                _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

                Running = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
                {
                    _logger.LogTrace("Connection task started: {Url}", _url);

                    try
                    {
                        await HandleConnection().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        _logger.LogError(e, "Error in connection task: {Url}: ", _url);
                    }

                    _logger.LogTrace("Connection task ended: {Url}", _url);
                }, _cts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew` -- that'll return just a `Task`, rather than a `Task<Task>`. That means you can't pass `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` but it looks like that's pointless anyway -- the lambda you pass to `StartNew` is async and non-blocking, and there's no need to spin up an entirely new thread just to run as far as the first `await`

Comment: @canton7 great explanation, you wrap it in an answer